# compare url string and menu string then add class using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a URL which looks like this:

```
http://www.website.co.uk/en-us/aboutus/thegroup/test.aspx
```

I have a UL LI menu on the page:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="/aboutus/thegroup/test.aspx">Test</a></li>
    <li>Hello</li>
    <li>Bye</li>
    <li>Something</li>
    <li>Cars</li>
</ul>
```

I am having the menu on every page and would like to use jquery to check that im on that page. If i am then make the A/li bold so the user knows they are on the page.

I have tried the following:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  if(window.location.href.indexOf("test")) // 
     {
        alert("your url contains the name test");
     }
});
```

But id like something that doesnt involve hard coding the values of the URL string. As if the user decides to add more links to the UL/LI the jquery needs to check the link and the url automatically and add a class to the LI (so that i can style it).

Hopefully thats enough infomation.

Comment: really? care to show me?

Comment: It's rather long but you can view this link. http://perishablepress.com/dynamic-body-class-id-php-wordpress/

Comment: After setting an ID to the `body` tag, use css to control it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is because the `indexOf()` method returns `-1` when the value is not found. You need to check for that value, not coerce the result to a boolean as you currently are. Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var loc = window.location.href;
    $("ul a").each(function() {
        if (loc.indexOf($(this).attr("href")) != -1) {
            $(this).addClass("current");
        }
    });
});
```

You would need to make the selector a bit more specific, something like `#menu a`

Answer (score 2):

This?

```
$('ul#menu a').each(function() {
   if(window.location.href.indexOf($(this).attr('href')) !== -1) {
      $(this).closest('li').addClass('yourClass');
   }
});
```

I added an id `menu` to your `ul` to basically differentiate your menubar with other `ul`s that may be in the same page. also `!== -1` as `indexOf` returns -1 if it can't find the string searched in the argument.

Comment: Can you write a description of what this does so that i learn for next time round please?

Comment: @sp-1986 oh u accepted other's answer already http://images1.wikia.nocookie.net/glee/images/7/76/Okay-Guy-Meme-Face.jpg

Answer (score 2):

`indexOf` returns -1 if the string is not contained:

```
(document).ready(function () {
  if(window.location.href.indexOf("test") != -1) // 
     {
        alert("your url contains the name test");
     }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  var liTest = $('ul > li'); // ' was missing
  liTest.each(function() {
     if(window.location.href == $('a', this).attr('href')) // 
     {
        $(this).css('font-weight', 'bold');
        return;
     }
  });
});
```